# A command that transforms a code comment to a title in a square with many comment symbols, also called an ascii frame

Tags: autocmd, command

How to create a command that transforms this text

```
# Title
```

Into this text

```
#########
# Title #
#########
```

- Is there a name for this kind of text? I have a hard time searching for this in search engines.
- I don't use this in well structured code packages, but I use this kind of titles in lengthy scripts, to break down the code in sections.

Comment: "Is there a name for this kind of text?" - I'd call it a "frame" or - more generally - a "decoration". Also, "border" seems to be used. Google for any of these plus "ascii". These things are so common, I don't think there's a canonical name.

Answer (score 1):

These comment boxes are called ascii frames, decorations or border. Adding the following to a `.vimrc` creates a `:Title` command that replaces a comment by a title in an ascii frame:

```
autocmd FileType python command! Title normal! A #<esc>yyppv$r#kkv$r#
```

The `:Title` command will only work for python scripts. It can be abbreviated to `:Ti`. It could be defined for different file types as well. A version that uses the entire line selection `V`, could also be defined as such: `A #<esc>yyppVr#kkVr#`, but it would then not work well on indented text, as explained in a comment, it would "replace[...] the indentation with more octothorpes".

`:help normal`

> If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used. Without it, when this command is
> called from a non-remappable mapping (:noremap), the argument can be mapped anyway.

Comment: You might want to use `normal!`. I think instead of `v$r#` you can use `Vr#`.

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble I updated my answer, is there a page that explains the difference between `normal` and `normal!`?

Comment: Yes, there is page: `:h :normal`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I find `v$r#` superior to `Vr#` since it works as intended if there's indentation before the comment, it will produce a box including the same indentation, instead of replacing the indentation with more octothorpes

Comment: @PaulRougieux I suggest you only leave one command suggestion in your answer, not the original one then the updated one

Comment: This feels like a game of vimgolf: `normal! A #<esc>yyPv$r#yyjp`